# Is "during any correspondence" acceptable?

Tags: word-usage

I recently had to email someone to ask them to use "reply all" instead of "reply" and I worded it as below:

**Please use "Reply all" during any correspondence**

I am wondering if this is correct. Any pointers will be appreciated.

Comment: Probably need more context - is this a work situation? Are you the boss? "Please use 'Reply to all'" is fine, but to assess whether "during any correspondence" is appropriate, I'd need to know the scope of the correspondence you are referring to and what your relationship is to the other person.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to be as polite as possible you could say "As a side note, could you please use *reply all* when sending emails" because what you've written sounds a little demanding and cold. However, if that doesn't concern you, what you've written is perfectly acceptable in formal contexts.